# Array/List from txt file in Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I was trying to get value from .txt file into array/list in python.
Let's say I have this data in user.txt :

```
  ghost:001
  ghost:002
  ghost:003
```

So, when I want to output it as :

```
  'ghost:001','ghost:002','ghost:003'
```

I use this function

```
   def readFromFile(filename, use_csv):
        userlist = '' 
        userlist_b = ''
        print ("Fetching users from '%s'"% filename)
        f = open (filename,"r")
        for line in f:
            userlist+=str(line)

        userlist = "','".join(userlist.split("\n"))
        userlist = "'" + userlist + "'" 
        userlist = "(%s)" %userlist

        return userlist
```

My question is how could I do this:
I want to print specific user. Something like

```
idx = 2
print("User[%s] : %s",%idx, %(array[idx]))

*output:*
User[2] : ghost:003
```

How do I form the array?

Could anyone help me?

Comment: do you want the user by name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store the users in a dict where the keys increment for each user:

```
d = {}
with open("in.txt") as f:
    user = 1
    for line in f:
       d[user]= line.rstrip()
       user += 1
print(d)
{1: 'ghost:001', 2: 'ghost:002', 3: 'ghost:003'}
```

If you just want a list of user and to access by index:

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
   users = f.readlines()

print("User {}".format(users[0]))
User ghost:001
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into loading dictionaries. This code should help you.

```
import json
import pickle

d = { 'field1': 'value1', 'field2': 2, }

json.dump(d,open("testjson.txt","w"))

print json.load(open("testjson.txt","r"))

pickle.dump(d,open("testpickle.txt","w"))

print pickle.load(open("testpickle.txt","r"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the file (one big string) split out into smaller strings, don't build up a new string, then split it apart again.  Just append each line to a list:

```
def readFromFile(filename, use_csv):
    userlist = []
    print ("Fetching users from '%s'"% filename)
    with open(filename,"r") as f:
        for line in f.read():
            userlist.append(line)
    return userlist

array = readFromFile('somefile', use_csv)
idx = 2
print("User[%s] : %s" % (idx, array[idx]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the `User['idx']` part of you desire.

Try to use [list comprehensions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk).
Use indexing rather than dictionaries if that's all you need. (I can add a dict version if the seconds part of the line is really the index you are looking up)

```
# read the file and use strip to remove trailing \n
User = [line.strip() for line in open(filename).readlines()]

# your output
print "User[2] : %s"%User[2]

# commented line is more clear
#print ','.join(User)
# but this use of repr adds the single quotes you showed  
print ','.join(repr(user) for user in User)
```

output:

```
User[2] : ghost:003
'ghost:001','ghost:002','ghost:003'
```